# How do I redirect or call a different Controller Action from my Controller Action in Magento?

Tags: magento, redirect, controller, action, call

I want to call `cms/index/noRoute` Action from one of my custom module's controller action, How do I do it?

I tried,

```
$this->_redirectUrl('cms/index/noRoute')
```

and

```
$this->_forward('cms/index/noRoute')
```

also few variations for redirect URL like '*/cms/index/noRoute' etc, non of them worked. How should I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it, and its so simple,

```
$this->norouteAction();
```

Since I'm doing this in one of my controllers which is extended from `Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action` which is again extends from `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action`, gives me the ability to call `norouteAction()`.

Comment: Just a heads up, this works sometimes but occasionally has problems with loading the wrong layout handle.

Comment: Thanx for the heads up, I didn't came across this issue yes. But its really something I need to look in to.

Answer (score 4):

Use below code :

```
$this->_redirect('defaultNoRoute');
return;
```

its work for me.

Comment: This is correct if I needed to use the Magento's default no route. But I have override that attribute, but in some instances I need to specifically call Cms module's IndexController's noRoute Action. Thats where I'm having the issue.

Comment: Hi try $this->_redirect('cms/index/noRoute'); Or $this->_redirect('noRoute');

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick (untested): `$this->_redirectUrl($this->getUrl('cms/index/noRoute'))`

Comment: Didn't work for me, may be I'm doing something wrong. It says - Call to undefined method Me_MyModule_IndexController::getUrl()